# Throttle Plugin Configuration for parallel pipeline stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

We have ec2 slaves launched on demand. I have following requirement, Wondering how this can be configured in throttle pipeline configuration.
1. Ec2 node should have 3 executors, I have set same in node configuration.
2. There are pipeline stages marked to execute in parallel.
3. Also one build should be running per node, it should be not be like if 3 executors then 3 builds running. 
So i have decided to use throttle plugin, Somehow I am getting confused how this can be achieved. 
(one build on single node)(multiple parallel stages on single node)
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have configured throttle plugin to maxTotal(10) and maxPerNode(1). I can see parallel execution on executor, but I can see two builds can run on same node. if maxpernode set to 1, it should run actually one build on my ec2 node.

Comment: Why another job or same job using 3rd executor